# Practical differences between control flow graph and call (flow?) graph?

Tags: static-analysis, control-flow, call-flow

Wikipedia has a definition for a [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph). I've also heard terminology thrown around referring to 'call (flow?) graph', but can't find any relevant resources. What is the relationship between the two?

Comment: I don't think that "call flow graph" is a standard term.  Where'd you stumble upon it?

Comment: I think OP meant "call graph".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wikipedia defines a [call graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph) as a representation of *the calling relationships between subroutines in a program*. In a call graph, an edge between two nodes `f` and `g`:

```
      f --> g
```

represents the fact that subroutine `f` calls subroutine `g`. A call graph gives an **inter-procedural** view of a program.

A control flow graph (CFG) provides finer "details" into the structure of the program as a whole, and of the subroutines in particular. For instance, the CFG of a subroutine `f` will make explicit all of the paths that are induced by a conditional branch:

```
                             / branch1 \
    begin --> condition -->             --> codeblock --> g --> end
                             \ branch2 /
```

This kind of CFG is used to build an **intra-procedural** view of a subroutine.

Comment: +1 from me.. BTW I would not use the definition on Wikipedia as authoritative.

Answer (score 9):

**Call graphs (CG)** and **control flow graphs (CFG)** consist of nodes and edges. **CG** is interprocedural, nodes represent subroutines (methods, functions, ...), while edges represent the relationship caller-called between two subroutines (e.g., A->B, "A" is the caller subroutine, while "B" is the called subroutine). **CFG** is intraprocedural, nodes represent program statements, including called subroutines but also conditionals, while edges represent the flow of the program. When **CG** and **CFG** are combined, it is called **interprocedural control flow graph (ICFG)**. **CFG** generation is more resource-intensive than **CG** but more detailed.